# Show a QWidget in virtual desktop with several monitors

Tags: python, windows, macos, screenshot, pyside2

I want to make an app which captures a rect on a screen, on macOS and Windows.
I use python and PySide2.
I want to open a QWidget to capture the screen when I have several monitors.

At the moment, I have an application that takes a screenshot on the main screen. But, if I have two monitors, I can only take a screenshot on the main screen, and I want to take the screenshot like if the two monitors are only one.

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PIL import ImageGrab

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(' ')
        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.3)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(
            QCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)
        )
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.showMaximized()
        print('Capture the screen...')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QPen(QColor('black'), 3))
        qp.setBrush(QColor(128, 128, 255, 128))
        qp.drawRect(QRect(self.begin, self.end))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = self.begin
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.close()

        x1 = min(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y1 = min(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
        x2 = max(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y2 = max(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())

        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()

        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        img.save('capture.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You could use the [`grabWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow) of QScreen: you could do that for each screen (see [`QGuiApplication.screens()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screens)) and merge them in a pixmap that includes all rectangles of those screens. It will certainly work on Windows, not sure about macOS.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your reply, but if I do this, the user cannot select the rectangle on the screen that he wants to capture.

Comment: Yes, they can: just use [`QPixmap.copy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#copy) with the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried, but It doesn't work on macOS. The solution should mainly work on macOS.